# Nested directive, child don't "transclude" correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/Dtg3N/

```
'use strict';

var navbar = angular.module('navbarApp', []);

navbar.directive('navbar', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {},
    template: '<div class="navbar"><div class="navbar-inner"><div class="nav-collapse collapse">'+
    '<ul class="nav" ng-transclude></ul>'+
    '</div></div></div>',
};
});

navbar.directive('navItem', function ($compile) {

var brandTpml       = '<li class="brand" ng-transclude></li>';
var dropdownTmpl    = '<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ title }} <b class="caret"></b></a><ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-transclude></ul>';
var simpleTmpl      = '<li ng-transclude></li>';

var getTemplate = function(itemType) {

    var template = '';

    switch (itemType) {
    case 'brand':
        template = brandTpml;
        break;
    case 'dropdown':
        template = dropdownTmpl;
        break;
    default:
        template = simpleTmpl;
        break;
    }

    return template;
};

var itemType;
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        itemType = attrs.type;
    },
    template: getTemplate(itemType)
};
});
```

In short, I would like to nest  in a  directive. It's nearly working, excepting that the 'transclude' thing is not working for the nested elements.

How can I get this work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following line:

```
template: getTemplate(itemType)
```

The parameter itemType isn't known yet resp. it is undefined. The link function is called later. You have to switch the templates dynamically in the link function and compile them with $compile(), e.g.

```
$compile(getTemplate(itemType))(scope)
```

Then you will get an element which can be inserted in the DOM.